# NgRx: Type is not assignable to type

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I am trying to use NgRx in my application and getting the below error:

`Type '(state: { userName: string; userMessage: string; }[] | undefined, action: AddMessageAction) => { userName: string; userMessage: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'ActionReducer<{ userName: string; userMessage: string; }[], Action>'. Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible. Property 'payload' is missing in type 'Action' but required in type 'AddMessageAction'.ts(2322)`

Here's my code:

> message.action.ts

```
export const enum MESSAGE_ACTION_TYPES {
  ADD_MESSAGE = '[MESSAGING] Add Item',
  ADD_MESSAGE_SUCCESS = '[MESSAGING] Add Item Success',
  ADD_MESSAGE_FAILURE = '[MESSAGING] Add Item Failure',
}

export class AddMessageAction implements Action {
readonly type = MESSAGE_ACTION_TYPES.ADD_MESSAGE;

constructor(public payload: IMessage) {}
}

export type MessageAction = AddMessageAction;
```

> message.reducer.ts

```
export const MessageReducer = (
state = INITIAL_STATE,
action: MessageAction
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case MESSAGE_ACTION_TYPES.ADD_MESSAGE:
      return [...state, action.payload];
   default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

> app.module.ts

```
imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot({
      message: MessageReducer, // getting an error here on message
    }),
]
```

> message.model.ts

```
export interface IMessage {
  userName: string;
  userMessage: string;
}
```

I have tried multiple things but nothing is working. I am using Angular version 14.2.0 and ngrx version 14.0.0. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please include versions of angular and ngrx.

Comment: @AndrewAllen, I am using Angular version 14.2.0 and ngrx version 14.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by defining the StoreModule as follows:

```
StoreModule.forRoot({
    message: MessageReducer as ActionReducer<IMessage[]>,
}),
```